# Is there a way to strikethrough a whole row in Markdown tables?

Tags: uitableview, text, markdown, strikethrough

I'm trying to implement a table in Markdown for tracking purposes. I know two tildes between texts like ~~this~~ will make it strikethrough text, but I was wondering if there's a possibility to strikethrough the whole table row like the screenshot shown below? Adding two tildes in all the cells of the table doesn't do the work for me as well.

[image: screenshot of example]

I tried Googling to no avail. I tried putting two tildes outside the whole table row and it wasn't working as well.

Answer (score 2):

The table cells are each parsed individually. The only way to apply markup to all cells in a row is to do so manually:

```markdown
| col a | col b |
|-------|-------|
| ~~nope~~ | ~~nu-uh~~ |
```

You could use CSS, e.g. the [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) construct to do this, but it won't work on sites like GitHub that do not allow custom CSS.